# Lorentz transformation of intensity

Tags: special-relativity, doppler-effect

I have come up with an expression for the way intensity transforms, however it is different to the book, and I cannot seee where I have gone wrong.

So we both start the same way:
$$
\frac{I}{I_0}=\frac{u}{u_0}
$$

The energy density is surely $n\hbar \omega$ where $n$ is photon number density.  If we imagine a uniform grid of photons and lorentz transform it, the photons get lorentz contracted together by a factor $\gamma$ hence the ratio of energy densities should be:
$$
\frac{\gamma \omega}{\omega_0}
$$

However the book says that the volume transforms with wavelength - which makes sense, there are a certain number of wave crests in the volume and this is constant, surely wavelength transforms as a length contraction (just thinking about standing waves shows this).

The expression in the book is:
$$
\frac{\omega^2}{\omega_0^2}
$$

I don't really see where I am wrong but clearly I am.

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what "the book" refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lorentz contraction doesn't refer to a moving pulse of light, it refers to an object at rest in one frame and moving in another. For a pulse of light the calculation based on wavelength is right, because you can imagine a pulse having a fixed number of wavecrests, and it will have this same number in all frames. Finally, to get the correct transform for wavelength of light, use that the speed of light is constant and you have the Doppler effect for the frequency.

Your point about standing waves is a nice example of a pitfall. A standing wave in one frame will no longer be a standing wave in another frame, so it's not so clear how to relate the Lorentz contraction of the distance between the ends of the standing wave to the wavelengths of the two traveling waves that make the wave. In the new frame you will get two wavelengths, one shifted up, one shifted down.

Comment: Yes, thank you.  They won't be standing waves due to loss of simultinaity and there is no restframe for light and hence no proper length.

It is actually your book I was referring to.

Comment: @Toby Peterken: Since you've accepted this answer, you should also upvote it.